# Constrain SQL results with GROUP_CONCAT and LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to constrain a user query regarding user roles (user or admin).

In a datatbase there is a table `user_scope` containing all user ids and the assigned roles (every user has one entry with a 1 for user, and some have a second entry with 2 for admin). I can't change that database architecture right now.

This is my SELECT on a table `users` so far which joins data from other tables

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT scopes.scope ORDER BY scopes.id ASC SEPARATOR ' ') as scope

FROM users as u

LEFT JOIN user_scope on user_scope.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN scopes on scopes.id = user_scope.scope_id
```

The table `users`

```
+----+--------+
| id | parent |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Alex   |
|  2 | Marc   |
|  3 | Cath   |
+----+--------+
```

The table `user_scope`

```
+---------+----------+
| user_id | scope_id |
+---------+----------+
|  1      | 1        |
|  1      | 2        |
|  2      | 1        |
|  3      | 1        |
+---------+----------+
```

The table `scopes`

```
+----+--------+
| id | scope  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | user   |
|  2 | admin  |
+----+--------+
```

This will yield something like this

```
+----+------------+
| id | scope      |
+----+------------+
|  1 | user admin |
|  2 | user       |
|  3 | user       |
+----+------------+
```

The problem arises when I want to filter the results based on one particular role. I tried this

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT scopes.scope ORDER BY scopes.id ASC SEPARATOR ' ') as scope

FROM users as u

LEFT JOIN user_scope on user_scope.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN scopes on scopes.id = user_scope.scope_id and scopes.id = 2
```

Or 1 respectively. However, that will not reduce the number of returned rows but will only NULL the rows with users that have not the scope `admin`. I also tried to use a `CASE` but I can't neither use this in a WHERE statement.

How do I reduce the rows returned in this context? Help is REALLY appreciated.

Comment: Your query is missing the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT u.id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.scope ORDER BY s.id ASC SEPARATOR ' ') as scopes
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     user_scope us
     ON us.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN
     scopes s
     ON s.id = us.scope_id
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING MAX(s.id = 2) > 0;
```

Comment: Great! Worked. And with `MAX(s.id = 2) < 1` I could catch the "users-only" case. Thanks for your help. It is much appreciated.